# How to identify if a webpage with status code 200 return unavailable page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a list of URLs that I want to scrape and store the webpage/file locally. I am using `requests.get` to scrape the data. I ignore URLs that return status code other than `200`, and those with `ConnectionError` or time out.

The problem is, there are URLs with status code `200` and do not return error, but the content is invalid.

For example, when I get request the URL http://www.canfor.com/_resources/company/code_of_conduct_2006.pdf

```py
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.canfor.com/_resources/company/code_of_conduct_2006.pdf')
print(r.status_code)  # 200
print(r.url)  # https://www.canfor.com/404-page-not-found
print(r.headers.get('content-type'))  # text/html; charset=utf-8
```

The URL is redirected to https://www.canfor.com/404-page-not-found.

Other examples

- http://www.coned.com/documents/Con_Edison_2008_Annual_Report.pdf returns a page with "We'll be back shortly"
- https://www.sedar.com/GetFile.do?lang=EN&docClass=2&issuerNo=00029532&fileName=/csfsprod/data139/filings/02023676/00000001/s%3A%5C857895.pdf return a page with "SEDAR.com is currently experiencing some technical issues. Please try again later."
- https://www.comvita.co.nz/_assets/Investors/30-June-2019-CVT-Annual-Report.pdf is redirected to https://www.comvita.co.nz/page-not-found
- https://content.etrade.com/etrade/extras/CodeofProfessionalConduct.pdf is redirected to https://us.etrade.com/pagenotfound.html

From what I see

- Invalid page can exist without redirect
- Redirect of URL does not mean the website is invalid

Is there any way to identify these URLs with unavailable page?

Comment: You could try with `requests.get(..., allow_redirects=False)` which will return status code `302` rather than complete the redirect. That may or may not be desirable if some links you need to access have valid redirects to the actual content you want.

Comment: Retrieving the status code just indicates the http status. You could also monitor for status codes like 3XX, 4XX, 5XX. There is always a possibility where the website's owner allows your request but maybe adds a maintenance message for visitors. In such a case, it's better to look for elements which are present on the page rather than to just rely on status code. For example, if you are finding for links, search for them within the response and if it's present, it's safe to say the page is working.

Comment: @flakes, it is not desirable as some links have valid redirects to the actual content.

Comment: @SinHanJinn, I am storing the webpage/file (eg: html, pdf, zip). Hence, I would like the webpage to be valid if it is of content type `text/html`.

Comment: @wavetitan This is going to depend heavily on the domain you're scraping because REST responses are not enforced to be uniform across all websites. Its probably going to be more feasible to create handlers based on the base domain of the websites you're scraping.